# JSON Url to PHP parsing

Tags: php, json, curl

I have this JSON url https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/tickers/eth-ethereum?quotes=INR and I want to display name, symbol and rank as the output. I have used this code in my php file but could not figure out how to display just name, symbol and rank.

```
<?php

$url = "https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/tickers/eth-ethereum?quotes=INR";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

Comment: what you mean with "but could not figure out how to display just name, symbol and rank."? Display how?

Comment: Thanks. I just need to show name, symbol and rank as output but I do not know how to modify above code so result shows name, symbol and rank. Do I add echo $name in the code to show name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like this:

```
echo 'Name: ' . $resp['name'] . '<br>';
echo 'Symbol: ' . $resp['symbol'] . '<br>';
echo 'Rank: ' . $resp['rank'];
```